# Join in Dynamic Query in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, join, stored-procedures

I wanted to join first query with next one.

```
    select UserName from UserRegistration where UserID = @UserID


     SET @sqlText = N'SELECT isnull(SUM(isnull(['+REPLACE(@columns,',','],0)),
SUM(isnull([') + '],0)), 0)' +' FROM dbo.timesheet
 where month ='''+ @strMonth+''' and [year] =' +
 Cast(@year1 AS VARCHAR(max))+  'and [Task ID] 
in(select TaskID from ManageTasks where TeamMemberUserID ='+ 
 Cast(@UserID AS VARCHAR(max)) +')'
```

want to display in single row.

My output is,

```
    Username 
-------------------- 
    myName
--------------------

    (No column Name)
--------------------
       49
-------------------
```

I want to display as,

```
Username     |     (no column name)
-----------------------------------
             |
   myName    |           49
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: `select (select 'username' username), 'value' value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add the username to your dynamic sql string:

```
DECLARE @UserName NVARCHAR(50);
select @UserName = UserName from UserRegistration where UserID = @UserID;

SET @sqlText = N'SELECT ''' + @UserName + ''' AS UserName
                        , isnull(SUM(isnull(['+REPLACE(@columns,',','],0))
                        , SUM(isnull([') + '],0)), 0)' +'
                FROM dbo.timesheet
                WHERE   month ='''+ @strMonth+''' 
                        and [year] =' + Cast(@year1 AS VARCHAR(max)) + '
                        and [Task ID] in (select TaskID from ManageTasks where TeamMemberUserID =' + Cast(@UserID AS VARCHAR(max)) +');'
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Can you help me to add column name for that dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

Try Below

```
SET @sqlText = N'SELECT ur.UserName,
isnull(SUM(isnull(['+REPLACE(@columns,',','],0)),
SUM(isnull([') + '],0)), 0)' +' FROM dbo.timesheet i
inner join ManageTasks mt on i.[Task ID] =  mt.TaskId
inner join UserRegistration ur on mt.TeamMemberUserID  = ur.Username
 where month ='''+ @strMonth+''' and [year] =' +
 Cast(@year1 AS VARCHAR(max))+  'ur.UserName ='+ 
 Cast(@UserID AS VARCHAR(max)) +') group by ur.UserName'
```

Let me know if you need any more help